# Template for regular posts (no custom post types)

Tags: posts

I'm running in a dilemma with something that should be very simple.

I have no custom post types. Just regulars posts. I just created a post with a category called "news". The official documentation says that defining a template for that category should be as simple as creating a `category-news.php` file inside the theme.

However it does not work, it keeps using the `single.php` file. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Visual_Overview) `category-news.php` would be *archive* template, that is for a list of multiple posts having specific category.

There is no such thing as template for individual post, having specific category, in native template hierarchy.

There are different ways to handle such, depending on your needs. Typical are:

- styling it via CSS (WP tends to output a lot of useful body classes to use)
- handling markup conditionally inside template file
- adding your own template file logic to native hierarchy

Comment: Er wait a moment.. If he has only one post in the category 'news' and he has a menu pick for category = news, why doesn't that work?  Clearly a menu pick for a single post won't work, but a menu selection for category = news should totally nail it.  Also, probably best to verify the slug name for the category is what you think it is.

Comment: @zipzit it would work for archive, but that's no "alternative" to actual singular view